# Vue-cli project including local package shows error on ie

Tags: internet-explorer, vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

I'm using @vue/cli

I have a Vue application let's call it **app**.

in **app** there's a component `basic`

```
import basic from './components/basic.vue'
//...
```

for now it all works fine.

Then I want to build my component as another package, so I moved it to **basic**(another project).

I use `npm link` to reference to that package(**basic**).

finally I can use **basic** module in my **app** like this

```
import basic from 'basic'
//...
```

When I'm doing this ie always goes wrong, but chrome works fine.

[image]

What's the difference between the two ways I import component?

Did I miss some setting? How can I make this works on ie? Thanks.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: It only shows "syntax errors"

Comment: Is that literally all it says, _"syntax errors"_? What version of IE are you using?

Comment: @Phil  I'm using ie11

Comment: What is your Vue CLI version? I'd recommend you have the absolute latest which is 3.0.1 (IIRC)

Comment: Thanks I just update my Vue Cli version from 3.0.0 to 3.0.3, and seems that my problem is solved. Did you know what the issue is that cause this error?

Comment: I saw some posts in the Vue forums about missing polyfills for ES6 arrow functions. I really wish IE had better error messages. Glad you got it sorted